# Bootstrap library with requirejs

Tags: requirejs, bootstrap-tags-input

I am trying to use bootstrap with require js. So far jquery, underscore and boostrap are loading fine, but I am having issues with one library not loading: bootstrap-tagsinput. How can I debug requirejs and see whether this library is loading or not?

Here is my common.js

```
    requirejs.config({
        shim: {
            'jquery': {
              exports: '$'
            },
            'underscore': {
                exports: '_'
            },
            'bootstrap': {
                deps: [ "jquery" ]
            },
            'bootstrap-tagsinput': {
                deps: [ "bootstrap" ]
            }
        },
        baseUrl: "/",
        paths: {
            'jquery': [
                '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min',
                'jquery/jquery.min'
            ],
            'underscore': [
                '//underscorejs.org/underscore-min',
                'underscore/underscore-min'
            ],
            'bootstrap': [
                '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min',
                'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min'
            ],
            'bootstrap-tagsinput': 'bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min'
        }
    });
```

Comment: This config is very similar to mine, except when my page loads, it keeps telling me that bloodhound is needed or typeahead is needed. The typahead-bundle is supposed to manage all that and there are some bugs listed on the twitter page where you need to rename one of the functions. Even doing that, I'm still getting errors.

Comment: Are you using the prefetch option by chance or just the basic functionality of bootstrap-tagsinput?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that 'bootstrap-tagsinput' needs to be defined where it's being used. For example, in a page that makes use of this library:

```
define(['bootstrap-tagsinput'], function() {
    // js for the page here
});
```

And in order to auto-load modules that should always be available (eg. bootstrap or jquery) we can do the same.

```
define(['bootstrap'], function() {
    // main.js contents
});
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. I have the syntax right but it still isnt' working. Do you have any sample code you'd be willing to share?

Answer (score 1):

Require.js is invented to handle dependencies between modules, so it is quite clear that you specify those dependencies in the modules where you use it like you said in your own answer already. The function given as the second parameter to `define()` gets handles to those modules in the order they are given.

As `$` is normally used for jQuery library, it is not a good idea to use `$` for something else, because this would create a lot of confusion. But normally you need jQuery in a module as well, so your `define()` call will most probably look like

```
define['jquery', 'bootstrap-tagsinput'], function($) {
  ...
});
```

In this case `$` is bound to jQuery, not to bootstrap-tagsinput. It is instead called via the jQuery mechanisms, so you don't need a second parameter in the function.

Comment: syntactically, this is correct bu the library itself doesn't seem to play nicely with bootstrap-taginput.